# Missing end tag in Xml Export by Response.TransmitFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using following C# asp.net code to export XML file

```
var myfile = new FileInfo(filePath);
            if (myfile.Exists)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myfile.Name);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myfile.Length.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(myfile.FullName);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
```

Export is completed successfully, but when I look into the exported xml file, the **end tag**  of the xml file is corrupted. it means some words are miising.

Can anyone tell me what would be reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for this code:

```
 var myfile = new FileInfo(filePath);
            if (myfile.Exists)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myfile.Name);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myfile.Length.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(myfile.FullName);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();                
            }
```